# How to start ipython notebook on ubuntu server automatically?

Tags: python, ubuntu, server, ipython

I set up a cron task to start a ipython notebook server

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/.../.ipython/profile_nbserver
exec ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
```

When I run this script manually, I successfully launch the ipython server, however crontab fails to launch it. I set up a log file and it is empty.

As a second attempt I set up a `/etc/init/myipython.conf` file

```
description: "ipython"
exec /home/effectivespend/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook --profile=nbserver --notebook-dir=/home/effectivespend/.ipython/profile_nbserver
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
```

but this also fails.

Is it even possible to have a server run ipython in the background? Is the crontab not the right approach to it?

I basically want to launch it and have access to it via remote computers.
(i.e. https://address:8888)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the environment variables aren't setup when using cron.  When you run your bash script, it has access to your ENV variables.  Take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26062135/4080476